# Changing checkbox status

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I change the status of a checkbox(check or uncheck), without clicking the checkbox or the label? Like how do I change the status when, for example, the screen width goes above a certain breakpoint?

Comment: `checkBoxReference.checked = [true, false]`

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need them in Javascript? if so, then it's easy:

First, get the width of the page and when it changes, do the action.

```
function getWidth() {
    if (self.innerWidth) {
        return self.innerWidth;
    }
    if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientWidth) {
        return document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    }
    if (document.body) {
        return document.body.clientWidth;
    }
}

function runThisOnClickOrOnLoadYourWish() {
    if(getWidth() > 1500) {
        document.getElementById("checkboxID").checked = true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("checkboxID").checked = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple way would be to give an id to the checkbox and then use it in javascript.

```
if(certain conditions are met)
document.getElementById("checkbox").checked = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

If (some condition you want) {
(document.getElementById("ur checkbox id")).checked = true;
}

Answer (score 0):

There is an object name 'screen' having 'width' property.
Hence, below code will work.

```
const breakPoint = 1365;
if (screen.width > breakPoint) { 
   document.getElementById("myCheck").checked = true; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample that i made for you it will automatically check/uncheck the checkbox depending on the width of browser

```
<p id="jsWidth"></p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" id="mycheckbox" value="Notify"> Notify me<br>

    <script>
        function getSize() {
            var width = window.innerWidth ||
                document.documentElement.clientWidth ||
                document.body.clientWidth;

            document.getElementById('jsWidth').innerHTML = width;  // Display the width

            var mycheckbox = document.getElementById('mycheckbox');

            if(width < 700){
                mycheckbox.checked = true;
            }else{
                mycheckbox.checked = false;
            }
        };
        window.onload = getSize;       // When the page first loads
        window.onresize = getSize;     // When the browser changes size
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that is called once the page resizes onresize = myFunction()  and include it in the body section of the html page. In the function, you can use window.innerWidth to get the browser width after a resize and then access the checkbox using document.getElementById and change its value by checking for your breakpoint using if condition.